# DateInput не подтягивает значение поля из базы данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, forms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить:
когда у меня в `settings.py` включено `USE_L10N = True`,
поле на форме не заполняется датой, в момент редактирования уже созданных записей, но при этом в базу данных отправить значение повторно позволяет

**forms.py**

```
class AkpIncidentsForm(ModelForm):
    required_css_class = 'required'

    class Meta:
        model = AkpIncidents
        fields = ['Date', ]

        widgets = {
            "Date": DateInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'type': 'Date',
            }),
        }
```

То есть `'type': 'Date'`, не дружит с `USE_L10N = True`,

**settings.py**

```
TIME_FORMAT = ['H:i']
DATE_FORMAT = ['d-m-Y']
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y']

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?
Если я удалю `'type': 'Date'`, то я не могу редактировать через поле помощи ввода дат.
Настройка `USE_L10N = True` мне необходима для фильтрации по датам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось добиться положительного результата следующим кодом:

**forms.py**

```
Date = forms.DateField(
        localize=True,
        widget=forms.DateInput(format='%Y-%m-%d', attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date'}),
    )
```

**settings.py**

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d-%m-%Y','%Y-%m-%d')

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

P.S.: Ответ взят на https://stackoverflow.com/a/62493594/17641696

Answer (score 0):

Если кому-то понадобится тоже самое для DateTimeInput:

```
<input type="datetime-local"
```

Можно воспользоваться таким виджетом:

```
widget=DateTimeInput(format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M', attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}
```